# Partial derivatives with $e$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

What steps do I need to follow to get the partial derivative with respect to $x$ and separately with respect to $y$ for the following function (I can't seem to get to the correct solution):

$$f(x,y) = e^{-x} + e^{-2y}$$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

With respect to $x$, $e^{-2y}$ is constant and its derivative is $0$, so the partial derivative with respect to $x$ is just the derivative of $e^{-x}$ which is $-e^{-x}$.

With respect to $y$, $e^{-x}$ is constant and its derivative is $0$, so the partial derivative with respect to $y$ is just the derivative of $e^{-2y}$ which is $-2e^{-2y}$.